# calculating the quantity of people in a given class

Tags: c++

how can one create a `class` with a `constructor` that counts the number of people who are alive,if i have 10 people it should count the quantity of people who are alive,people should be objects in this example,lets say i have a `class man` like this below

```
class man{

     private:
     string name;

   man(string name=""){
     cout<<"there 10 people alive"<<endl;

~man(){}
};
int main(){


}
```

i am getting confused on how to go about it,i really need a simple example  i want to use the set and get methods

Comment: why not go with the `static unsigned int counter`?

Comment: Why would a `man` know how many people are alive? You're going to need something external to the `man` class (or a static object).

Comment: so how can i go about it lets i have a static object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sane version of this would be to store your `man` objects in a collection, say a `std::vector`. From this `std::vector`, you could use `size` on the vector to fetch the number of items contained in it.

Otherwise, go with a solution that doesn't make sense in this context, which would be to store a `static` variable that is increased in the `constructor` and decreased in the `destructor`.

By the way, your `man` class has a few mistakes, the `constructor` is private and you're missing brackets... here's a simple version of what you're looking for:

```
class man
{
private:
    std::string mName;
public:
    man(std::string name="") : mName(name)
    {
    }

    const std::string& GetName() const
    {
        return mName;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    man Bob = man("Bob");
    man Jimmy = man("Jimmy");

    std::vector<man> men; // This will copy the man object, might want to consider using pointers
    men.push_back(Bob);
    men.push_back(Jimmy);

    std::cout << "There is " << men.size() << " men." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Known men are:" << std::endl;
    for(std::vector<man>::const_iterator itor = men.begin(); itor != men.end(); ++itor)
    {
        std::cout << itor->GetName() << std::endl;
    }

    // You could also iterate using something like for(unsigned int i = 0; i < men.size(); ++i)
}
```

**Edit**:

Lets add how to handle it if you're going with a static variable... see the following scenario (I collapsed much of the brackets just to make it shorter)

See the following code:

```
class man
{
private:
    static unsigned int sCount;
    std::string mName;
public:
    man(std::string name="") : mName(name) { ++sCount; }
    ~man() { --sCount; }
    const std::string& GetName() const { return mName; }
    static unsigned int Count() { return sCount; }
};

unsigned int man::sCount = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    man Bob = man("Bob");
    man Jimmy = man("Jimmy");
    std::cout << "There is " << man::Count() << " men" << std::endl;
    std::vector<man> men; // This will copy the man object, might want to consider using pointers
    men.push_back(Bob);
    men.push_back(Jimmy);
    std::cout << "There is " << man::Count() << " men" << std::endl;
}
```

The output to that will be

```
There is 2 men
There is 1 men
```

Wait... **what?!?** Where did we lose a man?  Well, this happened in the vector resizing, since we didn't define a `copy constructor`, the compiler did it for us, but the compiler wasn't aware that we wanted to increment `sCount`, so when the vector resized, new objects were created, old ones destructed, and `sCount` didn't get updated properly.

By changing our `man` class to:

```
class man
{
private:
    static unsigned int sCount;
    std::string mName;
public:
    man(std::string name="") : mName(name) { ++sCount; }
    man(const man& in_man) : mName(in_man.mName) { ++sCount; }
    ~man() { --sCount; }
    const std::string& GetName() const { return mName; }
    static unsigned int Count() { return sCount; }
};
```

We now have:

```
There is 2 men
There is 4 men
```

But **why?!?**. There are 2 `man` objects on the stack, `Bob` and `Jimmy`. Then there's 2 **copy** of these these objects in `std::vector<man> men` because the vector contains "objects of type `man`".

If we changed this to pointers:

```
std::vector<man*> men; 
men.push_back(&Bob);
men.push_back(&Jimmy);
```

We now have the following output, which is what we're looking for:

```
There is 2 men
There is 2 men
```

Hope this clears things up for you!

Comment: You changed his `std::string` constructor to `const char*`. Bad, bad, bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `static` class field to count people.

Such variables are shared between all objects of a given class, so increasing it in constructors and decreasing in destructors will count "people".